# how to show Progress Bar for delivery updation in flutter

Tags: flutter

i wanna add a progress bar in my app but i dont know how to do this thing. i just a beginer for flutter and wanna learn how to add progress bar i[image]n delivery Application

Comment: Use Stepper Widget  https://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/04/15/stepper-widgets-in-flutter/

Answer (score 8):

Six months later. I'll just leave this here for future reference. Don't use the stepper widget to achieve that. It's quite rigid. Use a timeline widget instead. Timeline tile has worked well for me. https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_tile

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Add the Steps**

```
// Step Counter
int current_step = 0;

 List<Step> steps = [
    Step(
      title: Text('Step 1'),
      content: Text('Hello!'),
      isActive: true,
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text('Step 2'),
      content: Text('World!'),
      isActive: true,
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text('Step 3'),
      content: Text('Hello World!'),
      state: StepState.complete,
      isActive: true,
    ),
  ];
```

**Add Stepper**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Appbar
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Title
        title: Text("Simple Stepper Demo"),
      ),
      // Body
      body: Container(
        child: Stepper(
          currentStep: this.current_step,
          steps: steps,
          type: StepperType.vertical,
          onStepTapped: (step) {
            setState(() {
              current_step = step;
            });
          },
          onStepContinue: () {
            setState(() {
              if (current_step < steps.length - 1) {
                current_step = current_step + 1;
              } else {
                current_step = 0;
              }
            });
          },
          onStepCancel: () {
            setState(() {
              if (current_step > 0) {
                current_step = current_step - 1;
              } else {
                current_step = 0;
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

> onStepTapped will set the current stepper count.
>   onStepContinue will increment the stepper Counter and setState is called on our variable that sets it to the next counter.
>   onStepCancel will decrement the stepper counter and moves back to the previous step.

**Complete Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StepperDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  StepperDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Stepper Demo";

  @override
  StepperDemoState createState() => StepperDemoState();
}

class StepperDemoState extends State<StepperDemo> {
  //
  int current_step = 0;
  List<Step> steps = [
    Step(
      title: Text('Step 1'),
      content: Text('Hello!'),
      isActive: true,
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text('Step 2'),
      content: Text('World!'),
      isActive: true,
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text('Step 3'),
      content: Text('Hello World!'),
      state: StepState.complete,
      isActive: true,
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Appbar
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Title
        title: Text("Simple Stepper Demo"),
      ),
      // Body
      body: Container(
        child: Stepper(
          currentStep: this.current_step,
          steps: steps,
          type: StepperType.vertical,
          onStepTapped: (step) {
            setState(() {
              current_step = step;
            });
          },
          onStepContinue: () {
            setState(() {
              if (current_step < steps.length - 1) {
                current_step = current_step + 1;
              } else {
                current_step = 0;
              }
            });
          },
          onStepCancel: () {
            setState(() {
              if (current_step > 0) {
                current_step = current_step - 1;
              } else {
                current_step = 0;
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @kunaldawar if my answer helps you then feel free to accept it

Comment: yes it is helpfull but i need more decorated and i have one ques that how to remove that two buttoms continue and cansel in that ui??