# food delivery in flutter change state based on Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a delivery food app on flutter. I have a stepper with 3 status :
1- order received
2- order processed
3- order is ready for pickup
And I need this stepper to get updated for any user, I don't know if my idea is correct but I'm thinking of using firebase cloud messaging to send notifications of order's state so that the stepper will change it states accordingly. if this is correct how can I do that(I'm kind of a beginner to that so any help would be appreciated), also is firebase enough for that as a database or should I go for sql?

Someone's asked similar question before [how to show Progress Bar for delivery updation in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856235/how-to-show-progress-bar-for-delivery-updation-in-flutter)

but it was more about UI rather than way that we can use to update the UI constantly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: did you find solution this is really goood question