# How to align different stages below a linear progress indicator?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-design

[image]

This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please prefer reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856235/how-to-show-progress-bar-for-delivery-updation-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Row widget just below the progress indicator, make sure that both of them have same width.
Set Main Axis Alignment of that row to 'MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween' and add all those titles as children of the row.
Here is code snippet to give you an idea:

```
Column(
      children: [
                  YourProgressWidget(),
                  // add any sizedBox for spacing
                  Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        // Place your text titles here
                      ]),
                ]),
```

Make sure that the number of children in the Row should be equal to number of segments in your progress bar.